# How to select the second highest salary row without using limit function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, limit

- I have a table with Name and Salary columns.

> But the doubt is how do I get the data of second highest salary details, without using limit function. I have a restriction for limit.

- Please help me to figure out the answer.

Comment: To select a specific row, you either use `LIMIT` or `TOP`; but `TOP` is just another form of `LIMIT`. Why such an arbitrary restriction?

Comment: Would be good to see a sample of your data.  The Impaler's answer looks good, but you may require a PARTITION BY clause also.

Comment: Is this an interview question? Are you allowed to use window functions instead?

Comment: yes I am allowed to use windows functions

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(order by salary desc) as rn 
  from employee
) x
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with MS Sql Server 2012 you may use `OFFSET` as part of the `ORDER BY` syntax.

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM Employees emp
ORDER BY emp.Salary DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

The offset 1 skips the top 1, so the fetch only returns the 2nd top.

Comment: I am guessing that _without using limit function_ he meant without using _offset fetch_.

Comment: Or he came from MySql and discovered that you can't use limit in sql server.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more approach.

```sql
SELECT  TOP  1 * 
from 
TableName 
WHERE Salary  <  (SELECT MAX(Salary) from  TableName )
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good habid to assign to variable more than once, but it works and do not need any risky window function.

```
select top 2 @salary=salary
  from employee
where employeeid = @id
order by salary desc
```